# How to get articles categories in config.xml - Categories / SQL form field type?

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, form, form-fields-types, xml

With this given category field I want to show the article categories.

```
 <field name="import_category" type="category"label="test"
            description="test" 
            extension="com_test" />
```

I know I need to write a query to pull the categories. But I dont how to use it with the xml in config.xml. Thank you in advance

Comment: Hello Parvvee - I am sorry - I am little bit confused. You are using already  category field, which should display a dropdown field with your categories. No need for a query. Now sure what I am missing with your question... Can you clarify what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting articles' categories inside the xml of your extension:

```
<field 
    name="mycategory"
    type="category"
    extension="com_content"
    label="Select a category"
    description="Select your desired category" />
```

In case this field doesn't meet your needs, you can fetch custom data directly from the database using the sql field:

```
<field
    name="myfield"
    type="sql"
    default=""
    label="Select a category"
    query="SELECT id, title FROM #__categories WHERE extension = 'com_content'"
    key_field="id"
    value_field="title"
    required="true">
    <option value="">Please select your category</option>
</field>
```

Note that the database prefix should be entered in the form `#__`

More info on how to use these 2 form fields:

- **[Category form field type](https://docs.joomla.org/Category_form_field_type)**
- **[SQL form field type](https://docs.joomla.org/SQL_form_field_type)**
- **[Joomla Standard form field types](https://docs.joomla.org/Form_field)**

Comment: thank you very much @FFrewin..  .. .thank you so much ... now that i understand to place the right extension when pulling out the category.. and sql way is also very helpful..thank you ..